# How to `export default *` in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I would like to put lots of constants in a file like:

**constants.js**

```
export const FOO = 'foo'
export const BAR = 'bar'
```

And I could import them like:

**index.js**

```
import { FOO, BAR } from './constants.js'
```

But webpack is warning me `export default` was not found in `./constants.js`, that also means I cannot do this:

```
import constants from './constants.js'
```

I've try do

```
export default *
```

just like

```
import * from './constants'
```

But it doesn't work. So is there any elegant way to instead the following?

```
export default { FOO, BAR }
```

Comment: I have `export const FOO = 'foo' export const BAR = 'bar'` and it works just fine, and I am using webpack.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to do destructured importing, then these are probably the two best options for you to use.

*Option 1*

```
// constants.js
export const FOO = 'foo'
export const BAR = 'bar'


// index.js
import * as constants from './constants'
/*
 * constants = { FOO: 'foo', BAR: 'bar' }
 */
```

*Option 2*

```
// constants.js
export default {
  FOO: 'foo',
  BAR: 'bar'
}

//index.js
import constants from './constants'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the constants in it's own constants directory,
which has an index.js doing:

```
export * from './constants';
```

Then it will work, I suppose

Answer (score 0):

Set all your const being exported in a file:
file.js

```
export const A;
export const B;
export const C;
```

And export them from a single file:

export_file.js

```
export * from './file';
```

So you can import them all:
import_file.js

```
import * from './export_file';
```